# Is $\|T^2\|=\|T S\|$

Tags: c-star-algebras

Let $A$ be a C$^\ast$-algebra and let $S,T: A \to A$ be bounded linear operators such that $\|T\|=\|S\|$.

Is it true that $\|T^2\| = \|ST\|=\|TS\|=\|S^2\|$?

I believe not but if not I don't understand why the last equation holds here:

If $a \in A$ and $\|a\|\le 1$ then 
$$ \|L(a)\|^2 =\|(L(a))^\ast L(a)\|=\|L^\ast(a^\ast) L(a)\| = \|a^\ast R^\ast L(a)\| \le \|R^\ast L\| = \|T^\ast T\| $$

where $A$ is a C star algebra and $T = (L,R)\in M(A)$ is a double centraliser (element of the multiplier algebra). Please could someone help me understand?

Comment: Check the properties of the operator's norms.

Comment: To answer your first question, look at some 2by2 matrices. Checking 2by2 matrices first is usually a good idea.

Comment: @JonasMeyer Thanks for the tip! I think I now worked out how to prove the equality, too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Counterexample for the statement:** Let's look at a $2 \times 2$ matrix example – define
$$
S = \pmatrix{1&1\\0&1}, \quad T= \pmatrix{\phi & 0\\0&0}
$$
Where $\phi := \frac 12(1 + \sqrt5)$.  Note that $\|S\| = \|T\| = \phi$, where $\|M\| = \sigma_1(M)$.

However:

- $\|S^2\| = \sqrt{3 + 2\sqrt{2}} = 1 + \sqrt 2$
- $\|ST\| = \phi$
- $\|TS\| = \sqrt{2}\phi$
- $\|T^2\| = \phi^2 = 1 + \phi$

Comment: Having gone through the trouble, I realize there's an easier example.  Namely:
$$
S = \pmatrix{0&1\\0&0}, \quad T = \pmatrix{1&0\\0&0}
$$
The failure of the statement in this case, however, is arguably less spectacular.

Comment: Why does $\|R^\ast L\| = \|T^\ast T\| $ hold?

Comment: @student I'm not sure. I'll update my answer if I figure it out.